# Returning multiple columns in Neo4jClient Cypher Query

Tags: neo4jclient

I am using Azure and finding the performance to be slow. In order to reduce the round trip time, I am clubbing the following queries into one query.

```
var queryItem = _graphClient
            .Cypher
            .Start(new
            {
                n = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU1),
            })
             .Return<Node<Item>>("n");
```

somewhere else in the code I have following statements

```
var queryItem = _graphClient
            .Cypher
            .Start(new
            {
                m = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU2),
            })
             .Return<Node<Item>>("m");
```

I tried to combine above two queries into a single query like this

```
var queryItem = _graphClient
            .Cypher
            .Start(new
            {
                n = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU1),
                m = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU2),
            })
             .Return<Node<Item>>("n");
```

I know above is only for single column so I tried using following return statement

```
.Return((n, m) => new
        {
            N = n.CollectAs<Node<Item>>(),
            M = m.CollectAs<Node<Item>>()
        });
```

but then I have problems with the following statement

```
Node<Item> item1 = itemQueryResult.First();
```

It says Error   Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Neo4jClient.Node.

Can you please suggest a simple syntax or returning multiple columns and a way to extract the first node? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're missing here is that the `Return` statement returns one object **per Cypher row**.

Your query is returning a table like this:

```
|-----------------|
|    n   |   m    |
|-----------------| 
|  Node  |  Node  |
|------------------
```

That's one table, with one row, with two columns.

In this statement, you are returning an anonymous type **per Cypher row**:

```
.Return((n, m) => new
{
    N = n.CollectAs<Node<Item>>(),
    M = m.CollectAs<Node<Item>>()
});
```

The return type of that method is `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`.

You're then trying to get the first *row* (an anonymous type) and implicitly cast that to `Node<Item>`, which is not valid.

You should get the row, then get the properties within it.

Some other things to note:

- You don't want to use `CollectAs` in this scenario: that will turn each *cell* of your table into an array with a single value, which just adds more indirection.
- `.As<Node<T>>()` can be written as `.Node<T>()`

With that in mind, here's the query you want:

```
var result = _graphClient
    .Cypher
    .Start(new
    {
        n = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU1),
        m = Node.ByIndexLookup("item_idx", "SKU", sSKU2),
    })
    .Return((n, m) => new
    {
        N = n.Node<Item>(),
        M = m.Node<Item>()
    })
    .Results
    .Single();

var n = result.N;
var m = result.M;
```

Make sense?

PS: I hope you aren't actually *clubbing* anything. Baby seals don't like that. You are *combining* queries.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed explanation. It makes sense. I am encountering two issues though. First is that the query is returning zero results if either n or m does not match against the index. I was thinking I will get either n or m as null so at least I can get one value. The other issue I found is that .Single is causing exception if indexlookup fails. I got around using .ToList(). So combining :) sort of works but need to get all results.

Comment: Single will throw an exception, by design, not fail, if you have 0 or 2 or 3 or any number of results other than exactly 1.

Comment: Thanks Tatham. Any other way I can get multiple nodes back by doing an index lookup? Currently I am doing 10+ individual indexlookups. If I could somehow combine them, I could save quite a bit of time. Only challenge is that some indexlookup (in combined query) may yield some zero results.

Comment: Focus on it as a Cypher problem, get the query working in the console, then bring it back to Neo4jClient after that. You might want to raise a separate question for help with the Cypher query, but don't make that specific to .NET (use raw cypher) and you'll get more help.