# Cypher Query Issues Neo4j C# Client

Tags: neo4jclient

I am getting an error on the following code that says:

[image]

Here is the code, I need this method to return the Max Value? is it an IEnumerable or an int?

```
public IEnumerable<int> GraphGetMaxVersion(IEnumerable<Node<VersionNode>> nodeId)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> nodes = null;

            clientConnection = graphOperations.GraphGetConnection();

                var query = clientConnection
                    .Cypher
                    .Start(new
                    {
                        n = nodeId
                    })
                    .Return((maxVersion) => new
                    {
                        MaxVersion = Return.As<int>("max.Version")
                    });
                nodes = query.Results;

            return nodes;
        }
```

Here is the query I would like to perform:

```
START n=node(2,3,4)
RETURN max(n.property)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
public int GraphGetMaxVersion(IEnumerable<NodeReference<VersionNode>> nodes)
{
    return graphClient.Cypher
        .Start(new { n = nodes })
        .Return(() => Return.As<int>("max(n.Version)"))
        .Results
        .Single();
}
```

1. I haven't tested that. I just bashed it out here in the textbox, but it should work.
2. If you don't need to return a complex type, don't. That is, turn `Return(() => new { Foo = All.Count() })` into `Return(() => All.Count())`.
3. If you don't need to use an identity in your return lambda, don't pass it in. That is, this argument is pointless: `Return((somePointlessIdentityHere) => All.Count())`
4. Use either Neo4jClient 1.0.0.570 or above, or change `.Start(new { n = nodes })` to `.Start(new { n = nodes.ToArray() })`.

Answer (score 0):

No errors are thrown when I made these changes to the method after reading [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431716/returning-multiple-columns-in-neo4jclient-cypher-query?rq=1)

```
    public int GraphGetMaxVersion(int nodeId)
    {
        int nodes = 0;

        clientConnection = graphOperations.GraphGetConnection();

            var query = clientConnection
                .Cypher
                .Start(new
                {
                    n = nodeId
                })
                .Return((maxVersion) => new
                {
                    MaxVersion = Return.As<int>("max(n.Version)")
                })
                .Results
                .Single();
            nodes = query.MaxVersion;

        return nodes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should so the following:

```
// Return Max follwoer node ID:
    public float ReturnMaxFollowerID(IGraphClient Client)
    {
        return Client.Cypher
          .Match("(n:User)")
          .Return(() => Return.As<float>("max(n.userID)"))
          .Results
          .Single();

    }
```